# How to filter date using datetimepicker via database

Tags: c#, mysql

Can you help me, i have a button to filtered data with date range base on my 2 datetimepicker (datefrom and dateto), Below is my code, and when i click the button it displays nothing. can you help me what is the problem? im new in C#.

```
MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=8888;password=888888");
MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from bio_db.daily_data2 where Date between '" + datefrom.Value.ToString() + "' and '" + dateto.Value.ToString() + "' ", mcon);
mcon.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
mda.Fill(ds);
dbgrid1.DataSource = ds;
dbgrid1.Refresh();
mcon.Close();
```

Comment: What is value of `datefrom.Value`

Comment: to get the value from the datetimepicker selected by user to be filtered by date.

Comment: Does it work correct when you copy your `mda` query to sql in debug mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi guys i already figure out the missing link. Here's the corrected script. Thanks everyone!

```
DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(datefrom.Text); //some DateTime value, e.g. DatePicker1.Text;
DateTime dtTo = Convert.ToDateTime(dateto.Text); //some DateTime value, e.g. 
DatePicker1.Text;<n>MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=8888;password=8888888");
MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from bio_db.daily_data2 where Date between '" + dtFrom.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' and '" + dtTo.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' ", mcon);

        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        mcon.Open();
        mda.Fill(ds, "root");
        dbgrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables["root"];
        dbgrid1.Refresh();
        mcon.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your `dateFrom` and `dateTo` values into `DateTime`

```
DateTime dtFrom =Convert.ToDateTime(DatePicker1.Text); //some DateTime value, e.g. DatePicker1.Text;
DateTime dtTo =Convert.ToDateTime(DatePicker2.Text); //some DateTime value, e.g. DatePicker1.Text;
MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=8888;password=888888");
MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from bio_db.daily_data2 where Date between '" + dtFrom.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")+ "' and '" + dtTo.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' ", mcon);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
mda.Fill(ds);
dbgrid1.DataSource = ds;
dbgrid1.Refresh();
mcon.Close();
```

Comment: it runs but displayed nothing

Comment: check your system `date` Format. I think you need to provide specific `date format`. Comment with your required `date format` then I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: my data table has date format "MM/dd/yyyy" ex: data
1/12/2016
1/23/2016

Comment: I have edited my answer. If `MM/dd/yyyy` not works then try with `M/dd/yyyy` Check and let me know.

Comment: still the same, it runs but nothing appears

Comment: check on `database` side copy the `query` u get after debugging the code and `execute` with the same `parameter` values. It seems like a `DateTime format` issue. comment the exact `date` column `value` u have in db and u get from query after `debugging` the code.

Comment: i run this 2 query from mysql and it displayed what i need.
1. select * from bio_db.daily_data2 where Date between " 01/12/2016 " and "01/30/2016 ";
2. select * from bio_db.daily_data2 where Date between " 1/12/2016 " and "1/30/2016 ";

Comment: Then the provided answer should work for you. Try to change ur **system date format** to `MM/dd/yyyy` on which you running ur code.

Comment: that' weird, still no display.

Comment: hi guys, still i'm not getting result, by the way is it true that mysql only calculate the the date with the YYYY/MM/DD format? i red an article that tells this.

Comment: Might be I am not sure about this will check later. happy to know that your issues has been resolved, I suspect that there is prob in `date format` and you found it :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is missing:

```
MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mda);
```

Sources:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-data-adapter.html
>   http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php

So the code should be:

```
MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=8888;password=888888");
string query = string.Format("select * from bio_db.daily_data2 where Date "
                           + "BETWEEN CAST('{0}' AS DATE) AND CAST('{1}' AS DATE) ", 
                             dateFrom.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy"), 
                             dateTo.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy"));
MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, mcon);
MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mda); //added code
mcon.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
mda.Fill(dt);
dbgrid1.DataSource = dt;
dbgrid1.Refresh();
mcon.Close();
```

Comment: can you give me the value for datefrom.Value.ToString() and dateto.Value.ToString() so i can adjust your query string?

Comment: how? it depends the value for the users what date to select

Comment: let me know if your question had been answered with my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114313/discussion-between-seryu-and-dr-stitch).

Comment: when i post i cut down the string to two lines so that its easier to read, but it turns out it causes compilation error if you just copy it. i updated the answer it should run now.

Comment: it runs but still displayed nothing

Comment: are you sure the selected filter have data in SQL?

Comment: try changing DataSet to DataTable.

Comment: i think the problem is in my datetimepicker format, which is set to "short" that display "6/10/2016", is this equal to "MM/DD/YYYY" format?

Comment: do i need to change my database format? my database Date field format is "MM/dd/yyyy", by the way i tried to change you query to "MM/dd/yyyy" format still no display.

Comment: can you please manually run the generated query in the database? can you check if the dataTable had Rows by debugging? i cannot help you if you don't know how to debug.

Comment: i run the query with date format "01/12/2016" it shows nothing, but when i run this date format "1/12/2016" it displayed the correct date.

Comment: i think the format of the datetimepicker is the problem

Comment: i had change the format in my answer from "yyyy-MM-dd" to "M/d/yyyy"

Comment: hi still not getting display, i've also change the datetimepicker to textbox still same, wanna ask if it is true that mysql and visual studio compute only YYYY/MM/DD format?

Comment: had you changed the dataset to datatable?

Comment: yes, but it gives compile error to mda.Fill(ds); 
"cannot covert to FormMysql.Forms.Datable to System.Data.Datatable"

Answer (score 1):

Your database has the `date` value as `date type` and you are comparing the `string` with `date` which will not match.

You need to `convert` `start` and `end` date as `date`

```
select * from bio_db.daily_data2 where Date between STR_TO_DATE('" + datefrom.Value.ToString() + "','%m/%d/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('" + dateto.Value.ToString() + "','%m/%d/%Y') "
```

You will need to specify exact format which is stored in database in place of `'%m/%d/%Y'`.

> Use Parameterized Sql

Your current code is open to `Sql injection` it would be better to use `parameterized sql`. Don't concatenate values instead `add parameters` to query.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to convert your datefrom and dateto  values into Database Date format and type

Comment: i already did, matched my date format in my database which is "MM-DD-YYYY"  and my datetimepicker into "Short" format which is "MM-DD-YYYY"